# How to correct this SQL query? SUM with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling to get this query right. Every time I change it, it breaks something else.

```
SELECT products.id, 
products.name, 
COUNT(transactions.id) AS sales, 
IFNULL(SUM(cart.price_paid), 0) AS amount
FROM products
LEFT JOIN cart ON cart.product_id = products.id
LEFT JOIN transactions ON cart.transaction_id = transactions.id AND transactions.status = 'COMPLETED'
WHERE products.user_id = $id
AND products.active = 1
AND transactions.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY products.id
```

The above is trying to get **ALL** the products a user has, regardless if they have sales or not and then show it's sales.

Currently, since I have the `AND transactions.id IS NOT NULL` it does not show all products. Only those with sales. If I remove this, then I will see all products but the `amount` field will be incorrect as the amount will be inflated.

These are some basic example tables:

```
# Products Table
+----+------+---------+--------+
| id | name | user_id | active |
+----+------+---------+--------+
|  1 | cup  |       4 |      1 |
|  2 | ball |       4 |      1 |
+----+------+---------+--------+

# Cart Table
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+
| id | product_id | transaction_id | Price_paid  |
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+
|  1 |          1 |              6 | 1.99        |
|  2 |          1 |              7 | 1.99        |
|  3 |          1 |              8 | 1.99        |
|  4 |          1 |              9 | 1.99        |
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+

# Transactions Table
+----+--------+-----------+
| ID | amount |  status   |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  6 | 1.99   | COMPLETED |
|  7 | 1.99   | COMPLETED |
|  8 | 2.99   | CREATED   |
|  9 | 2.99   | CREATED   |
+----+--------+-----------+

# Result    
+----+------+-------+--------+
| id | name | sales | amount |
+----+------+-------+--------+
|  1 | Cup  |     2 | 3.98   |
|  2 | Ball |     0 | 0      |
+----+------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and the desired results.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Where is the `user_id` column in the `Product` table? And shouldn't it be called `Products` like in your query?

Comment: A particular product can belong to a user. This is for a platform that has sellers and buyers, a marketplace. I have corrected the table examples with the missing columns.

Comment: I will wait two days so that I can add a bounty to award the correct answer. This has been a big problem for me for the past few days.

Comment: Why are you adding a bounty? You already have an answer that works.

Comment: This answer has greatly benefited me and I wish the person that gave me the correct answer to be rewarded. This is one of the purposes of bounties, right?

Comment: As I understand it, the purpose of bounties is to draw attention to a question that you're having trouble getting an answer to, by increasing the reward for answering it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: That is one of the reasons, there are multiple options to start a bounty. "Reward existing answer, One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty".

Comment: Where do you see that? http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties says "A bounty is a reputation reward you can put on a question to get it more attention for exactly one week."

Comment: If you start a bounty, that is one of the options you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `product` table with a `user_id` column is pretty weird.  I can see how a cart belongs to a user, but why would a product belong to a user?

For your query, I suppose you'd like to sum the `price_paid` of sold carts only.  Where a cart is considered sold if it has a completed transaction.  You could do so like this:

```
SELECT  products.id
,       products.name
,       COUNT(transactions.id) AS sales
,       SUM(CASE WHEN transactions.id IS NOT NULL THEN cart.price_paid END) AS amount
FROM    products
LEFT JOIN 
        cart 
ON      cart.product_id = products.id
LEFT JOIN 
        transactions 
ON      cart.transaction_id = transactions.id 
        AND transactions.status = 'COMPLETED'
WHERE   products.user_id = $id
        AND products.active = 1
GROUP BY
        products.id
```

The `CASE` will filter out the `price_paid` for carts without a completed transaction.

Comment: This looks great! I tried to do a similar thing using `IF` but failed. I will check this query now. Just two tiny notes, there is an extra comma after `products.name` and the 4th line should say `transactions.id`.

Answer (score 0):

The IFNULL function should be used inside the SUM function.

```
Because 
    NULL+10 is null not 10, 
    IFNULL(NULL,0)+10 is 10
```

Try This..

```
SELECT      products.id, 
            products.name, 
            COUNT(transactions.id) AS sales, 
            SUM(IFNULL(cart.price_paid, 0)) AS amount
FROM        products
LEFT JOIN   cart 
        ON  cart.product_id = products.id
LEFT JOIN   transactions 
        ON  cart.transaction_id = transactions.id 
        AND transactions.status = 'COMPLETED'
WHERE       products.user_id = $id
        AND products.active = 1
        AND transactions.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY products.id
```

Comment: -1 If you have two rows with values `10` and `null`, the `sum()` of them will be 10. [Example at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37f1d/1/0)

Comment: Yes @Andomar is correct, this is the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to perform an `INNER JOIN` between `Cart` and `Transactions`. This will get rid of the extra rows that cause additional sums.

```
SELECT products.id, products.name,
  COUNT(ct.product_id) AS sales,
  ROUND(IFNULL(SUM(ct.price_paid), 0), 2) AS amount
FROM products
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT product_id, transaction_id, price_paid
     FROM cart
     JOIN transactions ON cart.transaction_id = transactions.id 
     WHERE transactions.status = 'COMPLETED') AS ct
ON ct.product_id = products.id
WHERE products.user_id = 4
AND products.active = 1
GROUP BY products.id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39406/15)

Comment: This worked for me too. However, the query was very slow as I have millions of transactions and thousands of products. Everything is indexed well I think it may be because of the sub-query.

Comment: If Andomar's solution is more efficient, go with it.